# How to set identity_insert to on in sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get the command `set identity_insert table_name on;`, but for some reason it is not actually changing the attribute.  I've done it with the account that I created the table with, and I've also created an 'admin' account and gave it permissions to do anything (to the best of my knowledge).

Whenever I run the command under either account I get the result of '0 rows affected', then I am unable to run the query to insert the rows I wish to insert with the following error:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'table_name'
>   when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Additionally I've tried to include the schema name in the query like:

```
set identity_insert mySchema.table_name on;
```

but I get the following error:

> Cannot find the object "mySchema.table_name" because it does not exist
>   or you do not have permissions.

Also of note, my project looks like:

```
localhost\SQLEXPRESS
-Databases
--System Databases
--mySchema
```

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?  Thanks.

Here's an excerpt from the insert statement as requested, if there's a typo rest assured it is a working query in MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (id,name,size,height,width,created_at,updated_at) VALUES 
 (1,'a_name',36,36,36,'2012-10-24 17:12:24','2012-10-24 17:12:24');
```

Comment: Can you show the insert statement? Are you specifying the columns?

Comment: Have you tried without using mySchema and use just the table name?

Comment: @christiandev - that would be a different error message (something like "you must turn on identity insert and specify a column list")

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I am guessing that the OP might be turning identity_insert on, but not specifying the column which he wants to insert an ID into?

Comment: @Ellesedil, yes, that is what simply gives me a 'Command(s) completed successfully' message but doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: `set identity_insert .. on` is only valid on the current session and only on one table. Are you sure the `set` and the `insert` are in the same session?

Comment: @SWeko: Ha, I was just about to ask the same!

Comment: @SWeko, that seems like a very good thing to figure out.  Can you help me understand how I can check that, and then run the query in the same session?

Comment: If you are executing in the same SSMS window, it should be the same session.

Comment: If you create a separate connection to run the INSERT rather than re-using the connection used to execute the SET IDENTITY_INSERT, you probably run the two statements in distinct sessions.

Comment: @SWeko, your solution worked, if you'd like turn it in to an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[set identity_insert .. on](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) is only valid on the current session and only on one table.
In general, it's not a setting that should be used in real code, just for quick and dirty fixes (e.g., it's really useful when migrating data across servers)

I would recommend setting it `ON`, that executing the modifications in the same SSMS window, then setting it to the default value of `OFF` (closing the window will also work).

Comment: Strongly agree that this is something that should not appear in application code. It is used to migrate data and should not be used outside of a migration script. If you want to do this on a frequent basis there is something wrong with your design.